# How can I generate PDB files for a DUB package?

Tags: visual-studio, d, visual-d

I am creating a Vibe.D based program as windows service and I want to debug it.
I just tried to attach Visual Studio to the process but it was not loading the debugging information so, I was wondering how can I get the PDB files after a `dub build --build=debug` ?

Answer (score 0):

Dub appears to generate the PDB file as `%CD%\.dub\build\<config-hash?>\<exe>.pdb`. I had to use `dir /s /b *.pdb` to find it.

---

**Update:** I have sinced discovered that `dub` does not appear honour the `targetPath` in `dub.sdl` either for a `.pdb` file and so there appears to be no easy way to access it. I have filed bug [#1962](https://github.com/dlang/dub/issues/1962) to investigate further.